# Automatically copy a folder when it gets updated

Tags: windows, backup, dropbox

I am working on a project on my hard drive F, but my Dropbox-Folder is on my hard drive D. Now I want, that everytime I save something in the folder on hard drive F, that it get's automatically copied to the Dropbox folder so it can get uploaded and backed up automatically.

Any ideas how to do this with Windows Powershell or cmd?

Comment: Why not just add the directories to your dropbox settings?

Comment: @AthomSfere - This is possible? I always thought that it can only be one folder for dropbox. Wait, I'm just checking the settings

E: It isn't possible. I only can select which folders of my dropbox location to be synced

Comment: I just  checked, you can't. Nevermind! Sorry

Answer (score 1):

You can use a relatively simple VBScript to monitor the folder for file changes, and trigger a copy when they occur. Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10041057/how-to-monitoring-folder-files-by-vbs) should be a good place to start; additional documentation potentially of use to you may be found in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762064/windows-file-monitoring-script-batch-vbs)

Answer (score 1):

Just create a symbolic link and put the shortcut in the drop box folder. It's like a normal shortcut but the drops will treat it like a normal folder in your DROPBOX folder.
Or an easier option if you don't know what I'm talking about is using this tool that does it for you: [DropBox Folder Sync](http://satyadeepk.in/dropbox-folder-sync/)

Comment: This would be a much better answer if you expanded it, maybe including instructions for making a Symbolic link, or how to use the program?

Comment: Symbolic links in other OS's are used all the time.  Why doesn't Windows use them?  They are SO useful!